# Why does str.split not take keyword arguments?

Tags: python, standard-library, cpython, split

I came across this - in my view - strange behaviour:

```
"a b c".split(maxsplit=1)
TypeError: split() takes no keyword arguments
```

Why does str.split() not take keyword arguments, even though it would make sense? I found this behavior both in Python2 and Python3.

Comment: Python 3.3: works http://ideone.com/ZMACIJ

Comment: Python 3.6 works. Please specify which version of Python 3.x didn't? Only 2.x (2.5 .. 2.7) seem to exhibit this. [Issue 1176](https://bugs.python.org/issue1176)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

See [this bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue8626) and [its superseder](http://bugs.python.org/issue8350).

`str.split()` is a native function in CPython, and as such exhibits the behavior described [here](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/expressions.html#calls):

> **CPython implementation detail:** An implementation may provide built-in
>   functions whose positional parameters do not have names, even if they
>   are ‘named’ for the purpose of documentation, and which therefore
>   cannot be supplied by keyword. In CPython, this is the case for
>   functions implemented in C that use `PyArg_ParseTuple()` to parse their
>   arguments.

Comment: In the interest of self-documenting code, this is a shame.

Comment: `range`  also has this problem.

Answer (score 15):

`str.split` is a builtin method implemented in C.  Unfortunately some builtin functions/methods do not accept keyword arguments.  See [this bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue1176).