# How to invoke pandas str.split() and not python's built in str.split()

Tags: python, string, pandas, split

I am trying to locate all the rows of a dataframe whose one attribute (say id_proof) value matches to the second part of another column (say adr_proof) that starts with a fixed word (say PARENT) and also the corresponding values should match which are part of the same dataframe.

For example, in the dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd

main = {'account_number' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
    'id_proof' : ['A','B','B','A','C','C','X','Y','X','Y','Y','X'],
    'id_value' : [101,201,301,401,501,601,111,222,333,444,555,666],
    'adr_proof' : ['Z','E','E','G','G','I','PARENT A','PARENT B','PARENT   B','PARENT C','PARENT C','PARENT A'],
    'adr_value' : [11,22,33,44,55,66,101,201,301,501,601,401]}
main = pd.DataFrame(main)
```

I am trying to achieve :

```
node1    node2    relation
  1        7      parent-child
  2        8      parent-child
  3        9      parent-child
  4       12      parent-child
  5       10      parent-child
  6       11      parent-child
```

Below is my code. I am aware that my code is incomplete. I am stuck with the split() function. I am new to python and pandas and am not sure how to invoke pandas' split() function rather than python's built-in str.split() function. I have gone through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716687/why-does-str-split-not-take-keyword-arguments)

```
import pandas as pd

main = {'account_number' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
    'id_proof' : ['A','B','B','A','C','C','X','Y','X','Y','Y','X'],
    'id_value' : [101,201,301,401,501,601,111,222,333,444,555,666],
    'adr_proof' : ['Z','E','E','G','G','I','PARENT A','PARENT B','PARENT B','PARENT C','PARENT C','PARENT A'],
    'adr_value' : [11,22,33,44,55,66,101,201,301,501,601,401]}
main = pd.DataFrame(main)

df_group_count = pd.DataFrame({'count' : main.groupby(['adr_proof']).size()}).reset_index()
adr_type = df_group_count['adr_proof']
adr_type_parent = adr_type.loc[adr_type.str.startswith('PARENT',na=False)]

df_j_ = pd.DataFrame()
for j in adr_type_parent:
    dfn_j = main.loc[(main['adr_proof'] == j)]
    adr_type_parent_type = j.split(' ',expand=True,n=1)
    res = main.loc[(main['id_proof'] == adr_type_parent_type[1]) & (main['id_value'] == dfn_j['adr_value'])]

res
```

Please provide a way to achieve my goal. The output is another dataframe. Please excuse for bad code or any violations. A completely different approach is also appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Try using `re.split(' +',j,maxsplit=1)` or a similar fine-tuned version instead, from the `re` module.

Comment: I would like to use the pandas.series.str.split() so that the result can be a dataframe.

Comment: And what kind of dataframe do you intend to construct from a string that is split? In your loop `j` is just a string, so you need to do whatever you want to do with the split string yourself. But your next line uses `main['id_proof'] == adr_type_parent_type[1]` and that should work fine with a string on the right-hand side...doesn't it?

Comment: The resulting dataframe I intend to construct from that line is a dataframe with two columns first having values 'PARENT' and second column with values 'A', 'B', 'C'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your main question seems to be how to incorporate pandas split function:

You can isolate the rows containing the keyword 'PARENT' using this:

```
parent_main = main[main.adr_proof.str.split(' ').str[0] == 'PARENT']
```

Now, you can easily extract the second value:

```
parent_main.adr_proof.str.split(' ').str[-1]
```

Comment: i suppose the second line is : parent_main.adr_proof.str.splt(' ').str[-1]

Comment: This works!! Thanks. Solves my problem. But i am a little curious to know the answer for the crux of the question. Can we overshadow the function?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? You can experiment with something like `from module import something as str`. However I don't see the benefit here.

Comment: I want to know if i can invoke pandas.series.str.split function on a string object rather than python's built in string split function.

Comment: You can use the pandas version of split on a pandas series containing strings like I showed you, but you cannot use it on a string object directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't invoke `str.split()` of the pandas library in your particular case because you are using the `DataFrame` object, and this particular object does not implement `str.split()`. Only the `Series` object implements `str.split()`.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating this and also discussing about this in the #python channel on IRC network freenode.net, I have an answer for you. You can't overshadow `str.split()` of Python with the `str.split()` of the pandas library.

Also, the `DataFrame` object has no `str.split()`. I have read the whole API and also played with `from ... import ...` to somehow import `str.split()` from pandas and overshadow the `str.split()` of Python.

The `DataFrame` object you are using in your code has no `str.split()`. The only reason `str.split()` in your code doesn't throw an error is because it just so happens Python has `str.split()` built in and uses that.

The only pandas object I could find that has `str.split()` is the `Series` object, `pandas.Series.str.split()`. But you're not using the `Series` object, you are using the `DataFrame` object. I'm sorry, there's nothing to be done.

If you ask me, the structure of pandas is broken. You can't just import `str.split()`, because `str` is basically a `StringMethods` object and this object lives under the `strings` package, which lives in the `core` package, which lives in the pandas top-level package. It's a mess! I wasted 2 hours of my life to understand its package/module/object structure.

Also, `pandas.Series.str.split()` is basically `pandas.core.series.Series.str.split()`. I just gave up!

Try to import `str.split()` from pandas and you'll get a Nobel prize!

Comment: The pandas.Series.str.split method is simply not meant to be imported. However, it is super useful and extremely fast for doing string operations on Series.

Comment: Well, the OP wanted to overshadow the built-in str.split of Python with the str.split of pandas. But I already got the information from the Python experts on the IRC network Freenode that this is not possible, so this question wasted our lives. Moving on…