# itertools.islice raise a ValueError when used with functools.partial

Tags: python, valueerror

Considering the following python session (3.6.1):

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> l = [i for i in range(10)]
>>> islice(l, 0, 1)
<itertools.islice object at 0x7f87c9293638>
>>> (lambda it: islice(it, 0, 1))(l)
<itertools.islice object at 0x7fe35ab40408>
```

Nothing is unexpected here. Now, with `functools.partial`:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> partial(islice, 0, 1)(l)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Stop argument for islice() must be None or an integer: 0 <= x <= sys.maxsize.
```

`partial` seems to interfer with `islice` behavior in a very unexpected way.

What is the rationale behind this behavior ? Is this because islice do not handle keyword arguments, [like str.split few versions ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716687/why-does-str-split-not-take-keyword-arguments) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Positional arguments are passed on *after other positional arguments*. So `partial(islice, 0, 1)(l)` is the same thing as `islice(0, 1, l)`, which is not going to work.

You can't use a partial to pass in arguments in a different order; only keyword arguments would allow that. Since `islice` takes no keyword arguments, you *can't use `partial()` here*.

Your only option is to use a `lambda`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that doing:

```
partial(islice, 0, 1)
```

Translates to:

```
islice(0, 1, l)
```

Which fails because `islice` expects its arguments in a specific order. Using `partial` this way however causes the arguments to be passed in the wrong order. You can see this yourself if you pass a dummy function to `partial`:

```
>>> def func(*args):
    print('args:', args)


>>> partial(func, 0, 1)(l)
args: (0, 1, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

And because you can't use keyword arguments with `islice` to change the order the arguments are passed, you can't use `partial` here. As @Martijn Pieters said, just use a normal function or `lambda`:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> from functools import partial
>>> 
>>> f = lambda l: islice(l, 0, 1)
>>> l = [i for i in range(10)]
>>> list(f(l))
[0]
```

Comment: Passing the varying part to generate the partial is rarely useful.